# Running code x ticks after opening an inventory (Minecraft spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I have heard of ways to run code later like run task later and other scheduler methods but I want to do it inside of an event which I am having trouble with. Here is some code for an example of where I want to run it:

```
public class InventoryEvents implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public void onOpen(InventoryOpenEvent e) {
        // Run later code here
    }
}
```

When I try using code for something like run task later here or outside of it or even in another class I get a lot of errors relating to the class not extending JavaPlugin or me trying to use it in an event.

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create your scheduled task inside the onOpen method that's handling the InventoryOpenEvent.

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskLater(main, new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Run your delayed code in here
    }
}, 100L);//replace 100 with how many ticks you want to wait before the code executes
```

The `main` is where your errors are coming from. You need to use an instance of whatever class extends JavaPlugin (this would be your main class). I recommend passing the instance of your main into the Listener class in the constructor so you can use it as needed. An example would be as follows:

```
public class NamedListener implements Listener {
    private Main main;
    public NamedListener(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```